# how to fetch json from API using vanilla JS through Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

I am trying to download distance between 2 locations from tomtom api.

Protractor will not let me use

*fetch - fetch is not defined - please use import

*import - Cannot use import statement outside of module

*when I add

```
{
  type: module
}
```

to package.json  - protractor stops working, as no entire code is a module of ES

*browser.get - opens http with json data, but I cannot extract it.

Is there any other way? I tried to import json to a different file and export response.data, but the module error stops me from doing that also.

Comment: Can you explain your usecase for using protractor to call an API?

Comment: I am building an automation required for work, where Protractor is extracting geolocation, which then needs to be passed on to tomtom API to check distances.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, protractor is for testing web-applications, and it's api is for interacting with a webpage like a user would.

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is for testing angular webpages, but you can have the browser execute arbitrary javascript, but to use fetch, you need to use `window`

```
function getTomTomData() {
  //replace this with your tomtom api call, and transform the response
  return window.fetch(TOM_TOM_URL);
}

browser.executeScript(getTomTomData).then(res=> {
  //do something with the response
});
```

Comment: sry @Alan, but I am not sure what you mean by replace this with your api call. My api call is a simple http request => 'https://api.tomtom.com/routing/1/calculateRoute/52.50931%2C13.42936%3A52.50274%2C13.43872/json?avoid=unpavedRoads&key=*****'

I tried window.fetch('url'), but page stopped loading

Comment: Page stopped loading likely indicates an exception was thrown and not handled, which caused the page script to halt.

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to run node-fetch on my script as Protractor kept rejecting the import. I managed to to sort it out with **require 'https'**

```js
const https = require('https');

let measureDistance = async function(pickup, dropoff) {
    let url = `https://api.tomtom.com/routing/1/calculateRoute/${pickup[0]}%2C${pickup[1]}%3A${dropoff[0]}%2C${dropoff[1]}/json?routeType=shortest&avoid=unpavedRoads&key=uwbU08nKLNQTyNrOrrQs5SsRXtdm4CXM`;
    await https.get(url, res => {
        let body = '';
          
        res.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk;
        });
            
        res.on("end", () => {
            try {
                let json = JSON.parse(body);
                howFar = json.routes[0].summary.lengthInMeters;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message);
            }
        }).on("error", (error) => {
            console.error(error.message);
        });
    });
};
```

Also I used to put require on top of the file like in Ruby, which seemed to be another issue.